# Positioning inside <ion-slide> in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, frontend

A very simple question but can't find a solution.

I have a starter tutorial in my App (ionic 2) made with

Everything is centered horizontaly and up (next to the navbar)

I just want to put a beautiful

---

at the bottom of the ion-slide container, but i can't find how to do that (probably a simple css code)

Thank you in advance to the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `.scss`file associated with that page and put:

```
my-page {
   ion-slide {
      border-botom: 1px solid #CCC;
   }
}
```

`my-page` is the selector name of your `my-page.page.ts`.

If you want to be more specific just add a class name to the `ion-slide` component and use that selector instead of `ion-slide` in your `.scss` file.

Comment: I have pager=true so there is 4 small dots that follow the page, with your methods the hr goes after the dot, i want it to be just before